# Trigonometric function script?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

Is there a script for the ***sinc*** function analogous to `\sin` for *sinus*? 
If not, what method should I use to insert it in a equation?

Comment: Since it looks like you're loading the `amsmath` package, have you tried issuing the command `\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}` in the preamble?

Comment: apologies for the simple questions, want to make sure I'm not duplicating/ overwriting an already existing code.

Comment: If the macro `\sinc` were already defined, you'd get an error message, "LaTeX Error: Command \sinc already defined" when LaTeX encounters the instruction`\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}`. If no such error message is generated, it means you're safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\DeclareMathOperator{operatorcommandname}{operator name}` in the preamble for function or operator names that should be printed upright.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\si}{si}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \si(x) &= \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}  \\
 \sinc(x) &= \si(\pi x) 
\end{align}


\begin{align}
  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\si(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= \pi \\ 
  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sinc(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= 1 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]